# How to find extremums of function in R and determine their type?

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

Consider some function like f(x,y) = x^2+y^2 .

**Question:** Is there some simple way to find its extremums and determine their type (e.g. max/min...) ?

**I see the long way:**

Take partial derivates and using nleqslv  R-package find the solutions to the equations f_x=0, f_y = 0. 
Then calculate Hessian and determine the extremum type.

---

It might be there exists a shorter way ?

Comment: If you want to optimize a function you could use the builtin `optim`. Or look at the task view [Optimization](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html)